# Difference between project and System.Windows for iValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf

There's a few questions relating to this, but mine relates to a different error I haven't seen before.

I'm trying to use IValueConverter to disable a groupbox. Here's my error: `An object of the type "project.Data.IValueConverter" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter".`

I have IValueConverter in a folder called Data. So the structure of my project is:

```
**Project**
 -Data
      IValueConverter.cs
App.xaml
MainWindow.xaml
```

Here's my IValueConverter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace simpliphy.Data
{
    class IValueConverter
    {
        public class NegateConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value is bool)
                {
                    return !(bool)value;
                }
                return value;
            }
            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value is bool)
                {
                    return !(bool)value;
                }
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use it in my xaml like so:

```
<Window x:Class="project.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:project.Data"
        Title="Main Window" Name="main">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IValueConverter x:Key="negate" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

and:

```
...
<GroupBox Header="Device Stats"  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=tabBERT, Path=IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource negate}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="655,10,0,0" Width="191" Height="469" VerticalAlignment="Top">
..
```

What's the difference between project.data and system.windows.data? Apparently there is a difference between my converter won't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the class IValueConverter that you defined as a converter, but that class does not implement the interface which is leading to your error.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace simpliphy.Data
{
    public class NegateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                return !(bool)value;
            }
            return value;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                return !(bool)value;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you were wrapping the NegateConverter in IValueConverter class. With the above class, you can use NegateConverter as a XAML resource, and apply that resource as the converter.

Comment: Thanks! However, in my Resources, it says that NegateConverter does not exists in the namespace.

Comment: Actually, I just built my project and the error went away. Problem solved! Thanks for your help, it was a silly error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a class called IValueConverter. Put your class directy into the namespace.

```
namespace simpliphy.Data
{
        public class NegateConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value is bool)
                {
                    return !(bool)value;
                }
                return value;
            }
            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value is bool)
                {
                    return !(bool)value;
                }
                return value;
            }
        }
}
```